# IntellijJ IDEA 2020.2.3 Not Starting

Tags: intellij-idea

I downloaded IntelliJ IDEA Community edition from jetbrains and I installed it.
When I try to run it, nothing happens.
It doesn't respond.
Tried uninstall and install again, same.
Using Java 11.

Answer (score 1):

First check if the JAVA_HOME variable is set.
If you go to IntelliJ Idea installation directory, try running idea.exe or idea64.exe, it will clearly say to add the JAVA_HOME variable and also append it in path variable.
Come back again to IntelliJ Idea installation directory and double click on idea.bat file.
It should open now.

Comment: See https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544879. If you are using 32-bit Windows, installer will download and set up 32-bit JRE for you, run with idea.exe. On 64-bit systems run using idea64.exe. Setting environment variables is not needed.